# Changing Serial Numbers Column on existing data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains several columns with filled data.

I have a problem with mrn column (numeric) and this column works as a serial number and the value is generated randomly.

I want to rearrange mrn column based on an existing column (created_on: date with timestamp) by giving 1 to the oldest date and so on.

Comment: Does the `mrn` column have duplicates?  Does the table have a primary key?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function for this:

```
update the_table 
   set mrn = t.rn
from (
   select primary_key_column, 
          row_number() over (order by created_on) as rn
   from the_table
) t
where t.primary_key_column = the_table.primary_key_column;
```